# Need Some Advice For Media Queries

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor

I'm somewhere between novice and intermediate with web design. I'm building a site for myself in Wp (Astra theme) using Elementor. I'm previewing the pages in Edge, Safari, Chrome and Firefox dev tools. When I toggle through the different smartphone models, my text is right against the edges of the screen (portrait mode). I want to put 8px for left and right padding to give the text breathing room.

I started setting up media queries in the Astra Theme > Additional CSS panel, so the values would apply to every page. Just to see if this would have any impact, I put this CSS for an h1 class I created:

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
}
.h1-center{text-align:center; padding-left:8px;padding-right:8px;
 }
```

}

I know this isn’t complete, (no min value), but I am seeing the padding push the text away from the edge. What should I put in for min and max values? There are many different viewports for phones, so I’m not sure how to set this up.
LMK if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of media query max, min-width.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 600px) {
    .h1-center {
        text-align: center;
        padding-left: 8px;
        padding-right: 8px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. Where do you get your min and max values from? What made you choose those?

Comment: I share an example of a responsive media query code.
https://gist.github.com/monzuralam/db3c809a31d9314466a4a40436d4fc2d 

You can learn more from w3schools.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp